# apk into user app ( installed via adb ) and apk into system private-app

Tags: notifications, settings, system

Same apk if is installed into system app, have disabled the app Setting for Notification (APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
if is installed as normale app or user app, via adb it does not.

anyone can point me on what i missing for have "clickable" enable/disable for Notification Setting  if the app in system app ?

with app into system app:

[image]

with app into user app :

[image]